# require_once Causes 500 internal Server Error

Tags: php

I have a php script on my server, that I am trying to make sure require_once in order to just have a page with all my functions in it.

When I load my main page it loads with a 500 internal error.

My main page as this line of php:

```
require_once "functions.inc.php";
```

When I comment ou that line, the page loads fine, so I know the error has to be in the functions.inc.php page.

I then just tried to load only the functions.inc.php in my browser and that loads fine with no errors, so I cant figure out why the include is not working.

My functions.inc.php page pretty much looks something like this:

```
    <?php

    function one($arg1, $arg2) {
          return "one";

        }

function two($arg1, $arg2) {
          return "two";

        }


    ?>
```

Comment: My guess is it's an encoding issue or some weird invisible character in the script that's breaking everything when loading. Turn on error reporting and/or start deleting lines in `functions.inc.php` until you find the offending part.

Comment: That might be how your server is handling `require_once` failing to find the `functions.inc.php` file. It's called **require** for a reason. If it cannot find the file, it produces a `E_COMPILE_ERROR` level error and stops the script from executing. My guess would be that `require_once` is simply not finding the file, it's producing that error, and your server is handling that by returning a 500 Internal Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There error was that I had another include for my mySQL connection.

This include I had on both pages. This is why the error occurring since the included page takes all the other includes on the first page.

I basically tried to import the same php code twice.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably because your path is not right, or the file is not in the include path.

Try to use the absolute path, or add the directory (which the file is in) path into the `include_path`.

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $the_dir_path_where_that_file_is_in);
```

Answer (score -1):

Check your file location and also file extension.

Comment: This should be a comment.